# Delete all lines from QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, graphics

I am having a very hard time to find a way to delete all lines added to a `QGraphicsScene`. Let's say we have this 6 lines. How do I delete them later, after some processing? or in other words, how do I get a white and empty scene again?

```
QPen pen(Qt::blue, 1);
QLineF line(10, 20, 100,100);
scene.addLine(line,pen);
line.setLine(100, 100, 100,100);
pen.setWidth(3);
scene.addLine(line, pen);
```

By the way,  `scene.clear()` does not seem to work.

Comment: `addLine` isn't `void`.

Comment: I know. Do you mean the only way to do it is to store all the pointers for later deletion?

Comment: Sorry, I think that you need delete specific item but not clear all scene. By the way, I've tried `scene.clear()` in my own project and all items have been removed. Can you provide complete example which reproduces the problem?

Comment: I'm afraid that's it. I was just testing because I need a more complex routine which basically draws some lines and later deletes them. And the only way I got it to work was by storing the pointer on a variable (one by one) and later delete all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it storing all lines in a list and when I want to clear the scene I delete all pointers inside the list:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem *> list;
list << scene.addLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, pen); // store line pointer
void mainWindow::emptyList(void){ // delete all pointers in list (clear)
    int iNum = list.count();
    for (int i=0; i<iNum; i++)
        delete list.takeAt(0);
}
```